# Property on $n$-ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with the following exercise.

Let f be a scalar field continuous at an interior point $a$ of a set S in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $f(a)\neq 0$, prove that there is an $n$-ball $B(a)$ in which $f$ has the same sign as $f(a)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.

Choose some $\epsilon$ such that all $y$ satisfying $||f(a)-  y|| \lt \epsilon$ are the same sign as $f(a)$.

Then there is some $\delta$ such that all $x$ satisfying $||x-a|| \lt \delta$ have $||f(a) - f(x)|| \lt \epsilon$ and so have the same sign as $f(a)$.

Also, since $a$ is an interior point of $S$, there is some $r$ such that $B(a;r) \subset S$.

Let $m = \min(\delta; r)$, then $B(a; m)$ is an $n$-ball $\in S$ in which $f$ has the same sign as $f(a)$.

Comment: Nice approach Amzoti +

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you - have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f(a)$ is not zero, this means that $f(a)\in (-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. By continuity, you can choose a small enough neighborhood of $a$ which maps into either of these open sets.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more. I am not sure I understood correctly

Comment: @user43418 What is the definition a continuous function?